# How do I bind a XAML TextBox to either another TextBox's input or its own input, and then save the input to the data object in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have 2 pairs of textboxes for user input (see XAML below). In the vast majority of cases, the input for A1 and A2 is going to be identical to B1 and B2, so I added the bindings for `txtDataB1` and `txtDataB2` to "mirror" the input to A1 and A2, which does work in the UI. Data typed into A1/A2 saves fine since its bound to the `dataStore`, but I have some problems:

How do I save the values entered in `txtDataB1` and `txtDataB2` (either from manual user entry or mirrored data from A1/A2) to the `dataStore` object? I'm not familiar enough with XAML/MVVM/etc to know if there's a "pure-XAML" way of doing this with MultiBindings or something, or if there was some logic I'd have to make/call in the View Model.

```
<!-- Data A -->
<TextBox Name="txtDataA1" Text="{Binding dataStore.A1}" />
<TextBox Name="txtDataA2" Text="{Binding dataStore.A2}" />

<!-- Data B -->
<TextBox Name="txtDataB1" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtDataA1, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
<TextBox Name="txtDataB2" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtDataA2, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: I think this should work: bind txtDataB? to dataStore.B? (implementing INotifyPropertyChanged), which in turn is modified when dataStore.A? is changed.

Comment: That wouldn't update the UI though would it? Or i guess when the INotifyPropertyChanged fires, i could update the UI manually

Comment: Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged means you call PropertyChanged - this would update the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about trying to application implement logic like this in "pure XAML" and implement it in a view model instead. XAML is a *markup* language.

The setter of `A1` should set `B1` and the setter of `A2` should set `B2`, e.g.:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _a1;
    public string A1
    {
        get { return _a1; }
        set { _a1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); B1 = value; }
    }

    private string _b1;
    public string B1
    {
        get { return _b1; }
        set { _b1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    //+the same for A2 and B2

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

Saving the data is then simply a matter of getting the values from the `B1` and `B2` properties, not matter how they were set.

Comment: This does make sense, however I don't have two independent properties `B1` and `B2` in the VM, they are within an `ObserveableCollection<DataStore>` where `DataStore` is a custom object for this project.

Comment: @zakparks31191: I don't understand your issue. If you don't have the properties, you should of course add them to whatever object that you bind to.

Comment: Yeah this was the correct way of doing it. The underlaying issue was the the MVVM structure of this whole project wasn't done correctly, so after rewriting that then implementing this suggestion, it all worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using TwoWay binding, but TextBox is updated by `LostFocus` in default, change its `UpdateSourceTrigger` is also needed, the code will be as following:

```
<!-- Data A -->
<TextBox Name="txtDataA1" Text="{Binding dataStore.A1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox Name="txtDataA2" Text="{Binding dataStore.A2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<!-- Data B -->
<TextBox Name="txtDataB1" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtDataA1, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBox Name="txtDataB2" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtDataA2, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: This has the same results as the code I gave in the question.

Comment: @zakparks31191 Did you implement NotifyPropertyChanged for dataStore.A1?